# HTML with two video tags not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, mp4

I want to add two videos to a page but it will not let me. I am thinking that it is because it is within the same element. I have tried adding `<div>` tags around both but still no luck. It works with one single video tag just not two. Here is my video code:

```
<div id="advertising">
    <audio controls autoplay loop>
        <source src = "eyeOnIt.mp4" type = "audio/mp4" />
        <source src = "eyeOnIt.ogg" type = "audio/ogg" />
        <source src = "eyeOnIt.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <div>
        <video width = "256px" controls>
            <source src = "RachelMov.mmp4" type = "video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support the video element.
        </video>
    </div>

    <div>
        <video width = "256px" controls>
            <source src = "daddyWood.mp4" type = "video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support the video element.
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
    <script>
        $("audio").on('timeupdate', function(evt){
            var duration = evt.target.duration;
            var current = evt.target.currentTime;
            $('progress').val(current/duration);
        }); 

        $('#play').click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $("audio")[0].play();
        });

        $('#pause').click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $("audio")[0].pause();
        });

        $('#stop').click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $("audio")[0].currentTime = 0;
            $("audio")[0].pause();
        });

        $('#setLocation').change(function(evt) {
            var val = $(evt.target).val();
            var duration = $("audio")[0].duration;
            var location = duration*(parseInt(val)/100);
            $("audio")[0].currentTime = location;
            $("audio")[0].play();
        });
    </script>
```

I'm not quite sure what the issue with the video is.

Comment: This is also for a school project I might add. I am doing a website for my family and want to add video.

Comment: try fixing the html attrib spacing...

Comment: video width is just a integer and for video you need to add height as well like <video width="640" height="360">. and your javascript used the jquery format but I did not found the jquery quote like `$(document).ready(function (){ ... });`

Comment: Tried the Html part, it is fine to have two or more videos on the same page. Have you put the videos in the same place with the html page?

Comment: The videos are in the same place.

Comment: The spacing has been working as is everywhere else. I have used just width for the video everywhere else as well.

Comment: May I ask what web browser do you use? Because the Html part is absolute  fine with most browsers I think. I tried safari, chrome, firefox they all work fine. And by the way, what do you mean it is not working? You cannot play the second one? or the second video does not display at all? or something else?

Comment: Both videos will not even load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found syntax issues as well as logic issues. The file  RachelMov.mmp4 should be Rachel.mp4 as I had changed the file name and mmp4 is the wrong syntax. The preload=none tag also caused the videos to not be accessible at all.

Comment: I doubt it, the `preload="none"` will never make the video unaccessible at all, it is a standard setting that works for all browsers except old IEs.

Comment: When I removed it, it started working